# How to add text field in views to add content to other table inside a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Im new to ror so sorry if that's a really basic question.

So, in my app i have quizzes and each quiz, beside questions and answers, should have 5 links.

```
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :questions
  has_many :links
end

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :quizzes
end
```

Schema looks like this:

```
create_table "links", force: true do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.string  "www"
    t.integer "quiz_id"
  end

  create_table "questions", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "quiz_id"
  end

  create_table "quizzes", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Now, in views I want to add links as i Add/Edit my quiz.
View for form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@quiz) do |f| %>
  <% if @quiz.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@quiz.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this quiz from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @quiz.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
    <%= **THIS IS PLACE FOR TEXT FIELD FOR LINK_NAME AND LINK_WWW** %>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

How do I create a form to add the links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fields_for`:

```
<%= f.label :content %><br>
<%= f.text_field :content %>
<%= f.fields_for @quiz.links.new do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.label :name %>
  <%= ff.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

And allow the Quiz to update the Link records associated:

```
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :links
```